# How do I write REST service to support multiple Get Endpoints in .net MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I am familiar with how to write the default Get, Post, Put, Delete

```
//GET api/customer
public string Get(){}

//GET api/customer/id
public string Get(int id){}

//POST api/customer
 public void Post([FromBody]string value){}

//PUT api/customer/id
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value){}

//DELETE api/customer/id
 public void Delete(int id){}
```

But how would I write add another Get endpoint w/o having to create a whole new controller?  I want to grab the customer's metadata?  do I need to make any changes to the routeConfig?  if so how would I do that?  and then how would I use the new route in javascript?

```
//GET api/customer/GetMetaData
 public string GetMetaData(){
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Attribute **Route**. This attribute was added in WebApi 20 and you can use it at Method level to define new route or more routes and the way you use it is like `[Route("Url/route1/route1")]`:

Using one of your examples above it will be like:

```
//GET api/customer/GetMetaData
[Route("api/customer/GetMetaData")]
public string Get2(){
      //your code goes here
}
```

If you will be declaring several Routes in your class then you can use **RoutePrefix** attribute like `[RoutePrefix("url")]` at class level. This will set a new base URL for all methods your in Controller class.

For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api2/some")]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    // GET api2/some
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Some> Get() { ... }

    // GET api2/some/5 
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public Some Get(int id) { ... } 

}
```

> **Note:** In the example above I showed one example where Route allowed us to set type constraints as well.

Comment: Thanks!! that was it.   [Route("api/customer/GetMetaData")].  I was googling "multiple endpoints" when I should have been googling for 
route attributes.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2